# WSL not running

Tags: linux, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, linux-distributions

Not much to say here, but whenever I try to run `wsl` or try to run a distro on any kind of terminal, be it `cmd`, `powershell`, or even `git bash`, it does not do anything, that is it produces no output.

This is what it looks like:

```bash
$ wsl
```

```bash
$ ubuntu
```

```bash
$ kali
```

I run Windows 10.

### EDIT

Apparently the distros started installing after keeping the window open for some time. Both distros and wsl command now work fine.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more details.  Are you running these commands in Command Prompt, PowerShell, or Windows Terminal.  You need to edit your question to provide as much detail as possible.  If you have not installed those instances from the WIndows Store you need to do so.

Comment: Thanks for reposting over here.  Your question looks pretty clear to me (and did on Stack Overflow as well, just that it was off-topic there), but just to confirm, when you run `wsl` from PowerShell, you receive no output, no error message, nothing -- Correct?

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried to run the commands in all three. I have installed it correctly, I know that as it was working before.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yes, I receive no output, although the process seems to have started.

Comment: Event Viewer? Have you checked the logs Windows provides to see what might be happening?

Comment: @music2myear How do you trace and solve the error with that? I don't know as I have never opened the log file or event viewer.

Comment: When troubleshooting issues in Windows, especially for Microsoft products running on or even built in to Windows, you start with Event Viewer, which is Microsoft's primary logging method. Even if it doesn't mean anything to you, the information in it (and it is generally quite well documented) is required to make a good question here.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling then reinstalling it? Sounds like https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8300